# Conflict between ifpdf, pdfpages, and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pdfpages, auto-pst-pdf

I want to have a centred title page for my twoside report document and I am following these instructions:

[Centered title page in twoside report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57158/centered-title-page-in-twoside-report)

Here is a minimum (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage{tikz}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-eucl}
\fi

\begin{document}

\includepdf{pdf-sample.pdf}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}

This is content.

\end{document}
```

But the first page appears to be blank.
As soon as I remove either `\ifpdf...` or `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, the title page appears in my document.
I use `pdflatex --shell-escape` for compiling.
Unfortunately, I need both options for my document. Any help how to work around this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What does pdf-sample.pdf contain? Is it a huge file?

Comment: It is just an example for testing. You can download it here: http://www.hollywood-arts.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/pdf-sample.pdf

Answer (score 1):

that is a bug in the current `tikz`. Use:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\includepdf{pdf-sample.pdf}

\tableofcontents   
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}

This is content.   
\end{document}
```

However, this gives a warning that `auto-pst-pdf` cant create a file. But that doesn't hurt, because there is no file to create ...

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not solve the problem. The first page is still blank.

Comment: not for me. I am using up-to-date TeXLive 2014

Comment: Me too: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)

Comment: Try `\ifpdf\includepdf{pdf-sample.pdf}\fi`. However, here is my generated PDF: http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/tmp/test.pdf

Comment: I am sorry, but the problem still there.

Comment: Herbert, your code does nothing if auto-pst-pdf is loaded, so what is its intention?

Comment: provide your file list. You get it with `\listfiles` in the preamble at the end of your log file. And what happens if you write a single word before `\includepdf`? Is the empty page still there?

Comment: @Ulrike, I konw. But if I understand Alfred well, then the above code creates an empty page before `\includepdf`

Comment: No it creates an empty page *instead* of the \includepdf. `\includepdf` works again if one moves pdfpages behind tikz (the problem seems to be atbegshi: if is loaded before tikz, tikz reverts the atbegshi code).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ah ok. However, I get a correct output with the included pdf page. Working under Linux and TL

Comment: @Alfred: my fault. I'd forgotten that I fixed the `pgfutil-latex.def` file of `tikz` in my local tree. However, put the http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/tmp/pgfutil-latex.def into your documents directory and try again with my edited example above.

Comment: It make a lot more sense if the code is in the def ;-). But is it safe to disable the preview "hack" completly when auto-pst-pdf is loaded?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: yes

Comment: And do you know why? What does auto-pst-pdf do that removes the necessity of the hack? pgf probably didn't add it only for fun ;-).