# UNAM thesis title page (portada tesis UNAM)

Tags: titles, thesis

I am trying to write latex code to generate a title page for a UNAM's thesis, which has an unusual graphic design. It's hard to define the position of each element and get the desired result.  It will be very much appreciated if somebody can share code to resolve this problem.

UNAM = Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México (Spanish),
        National Autonomous University of Mexico (English)
For more information, see [the Wikipedia entry for UNAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Autonomous_University_of_Mexico).

Comment: Hi and welcome, your question is specific to *UNAM*. I guess i am not the only one around here that does not know what UNAM is. We need a bit more information. We can surely help with special problems, recreating a whole titlepage will need a bit of effort and free time. Who has that these days? For a first intro, consider [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: Using google i meanwhile found that out. You can add the information to the question, some explanations might also help. You already provided an answer to help others. I order to get this found by users using google, you need to provide some keywords they might trigger.

Comment: btw, you could have left a comment, that you are going to provide an answer yourself to get some archivable content on the site.

Comment: Hint: nobody knows what happens in the future. You can share this on github or something similar. That also gives other more possibilities to contribute by suggesting improvements. This site here is for quesitons/answers. But not developing code like whole thesis templates (which might come out of this).

Comment: Hi Johanes_B, thank you very for your welcome, effectively you're right,  I need to provide more details about UNAM, UNAM stands for Universidad Nacional Autonoma de Mexico in Spanish or National Autonomous University of Mexico in English. For more information about UNAM review the followin link from wikipedia [UNAM]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Autonomous_University_of_Mexico}

My problem was that I couldn't find a satisfactory solution to design a title page with the format required for a UNAM thesis and I wanted to share my solution to help other people.

Comment: the link needs to be enclosed in parenthesis `[link name](link target)` ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It took me time to write good code to generate a title page for a UNAM thesis and I think this could be very useful for somebody that is writing his/her thesis work in latex

The key to resolve the problem was to use the minipage environment. To use it correctly I found very useful [Wikipedia's documentation : Latex/Boxes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes)
.  The trick was to use this environment to make a grid for title page to correctly put each element of the title page for the thesis

The code I wrote was the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{escudo}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    {\scshape Universidad Nacional Aut\'onoma de M\'exico}
    \vspace{.3cm}
    \hrule height2.5pt
    \vspace{.1cm}
    \hrule height1pt
    \vspace{.3cm}
    {\scshape  Facultad de Ciencias}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\hskip2pt
\vrule width2.5pt height10cm
        \hskip1mm
        \vrule width1pt height10cm \\
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{escudoFC}
        \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    {\Large \scshape {T\'itulo de la tesis}}

    \vspace{2cm}

    \makebox[5cm][c]{\LARGE TESIS}  \\[8pt]
    QUE PARA OBTENER EL T\'iTULO DE:\\[5pt]
    {\large \textbf{{t\'itulo}}}\\[40pt]            
    PRESENTA:\\[5pt]
    \textbf{{Nombre del tesista}}

    \vspace{1cm}

    {\small DIRECTOR DEL TRABAJO:\\ {Nombre del director del trabajo}}

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    {Lugar,}{ }{Fecha}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This code produce the following output

[image: UNAM thesis title page]

To view the use of minipage environment to design the title page you can use the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
% port
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{escudo}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        {\scshape Universidad Nacional Aut\'onoma de M\'exico}
        \vspace{.3cm}
        \hrule height2.5pt
        \vspace{.1cm}
        \hrule height1pt
        \vspace{.3cm}
        {\scshape  Facultad de Ciencias}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \hskip2pt
    \vrule width2.5pt height10cm
        \hskip1mm
        \vrule width1pt height10cm \\
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{escudoFC}
        \end{center}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        {\Large \scshape {T\'itulo de la tesis}}

        \vspace{2cm}

        \makebox[5cm][c]{\LARGE TESIS}  \\[8pt]
        QUE PARA OBTENER EL T\'ITULO DE:\\[5pt]
        {\large \textbf{{t\'itulo}}}\\[40pt]            
        PRESENTA:\\[5pt]
        \textbf{{Nombre del tesista}}

        \vspace{1cm}

        {\small DIRECTOR DEL TRABAJO:\\ {Nombre del director del trabajo}}

        \vspace{0.5cm}

        {Lugar,}{ }{Fecha}
      \end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

To produce the followint output

[image]

I hope this will be useful for somebody that writes his thesis work in latex

Comment: You clearly got the job done in an ellegant way. But this titlepage is displayed a little bit too small. Do you know a method to scale or extend the titlepage to the whole page?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm apologize so much for the delay about to propose a better way to create the cover for a UNAM thesis.

The delay was caused because I was tracking the link with the information that helped me to determine a better way to make a  cover page.  The searching of this link was essential, because it's important to be grateful when somebody share her/his time and work with the goal to help somebody else.

Well, the information for the question

[Centered title page in twoside report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57158/centered-title-page-in-twoside-report)

helped me to define a better cover.  The approach suggested by schlamar in the previous link it's the following

1. Separate the creation of the cover.
2. Include the cover with pdfpages.

With the help of this approach, I define the following cover with a better size and presentation

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=11pt,
    a4paper
   ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeall,bindingoffset=0cm,margin=2cm,
            marginparsep=0cm,marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.17\textheight][c]{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{unam}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.17\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \vspace{.3cm}
                \textsc{\large Universidad Nacional Aut\'onoma de M\'exico}\\[0.5cm]
                \vspace{.3cm}
                \hrule height2.5pt
                \vspace{.1cm}
                \hrule height1pt
                \vspace{.8cm}
                \textsc{\LARGE Facultad de Ciencias}\\[0.5cm] %
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}[c][0.81\textheight][t]{0.25\textwidth}
            \vspace*{5mm}
            \begin{center}
                \hskip2pt
                \vrule width2.5pt height13cm
                \hskip1mm
                \vrule width1pt height13cm \\
                \includegraphics[height=5cm]{escudoFC}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.81\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \vspace{1cm}

                {\Huge\scshape Title}\\[.2in]

                \vspace{2cm}            

                \textsc{\LARGE TESIS}\\[0.5cm]
                \textsc{\large que para obtener el t\'itulo de}\\[0.5cm]
                \textsc{\large t\'itulo}\\[0.5cm]
                \textsc{\large presenta}\\[0.5cm]
                \textsc{\large \textbf{Nombre del tesista}}\\[2cm]          

                \vspace{0.5cm}

                {\large\scshape Director del trabajo:\\[0.3cm] {Nombre del director del trabajo}}\\[.2in]

                \vspace{0.5cm}

                {Lugar,}{ }{Fecha}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The following code it's a way of how to include the cover

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf{cover.pdf}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The following image compares the two cover pages proposed in this question, showing that the second approach it's better.

[image]

Comment: Excelente, me basé en tu formato para hacer la portada de lo que será mi tesis, la modifiqué y con ayuda de otro montón de preguntas en este sitio la hice compatible con el paquete Classicthesis, me costó mucho tiempo y esfuerzo hacer que compile sin errores ni advertencia pero finalmente lo hace y se ve muy bien. Sólo quiero agradecer el esfuerzo que hiciste en diseñar esta portada

Comment: Hola Paul, muchas gracias, es sumamente satisfactorio saber que la portada es de utilidad.  Saludos Diego

Answer (score 0):

Here you can make your unam thesis online -> http://computo.fciencias.unam.mx/latex/portadaTesis.php

Answer (score 0):

Here it is! The [LaTeX GitHub project for the National Autonomous University of Mexico](https://github.com/JuIioCesar/Tesis) Feel free to fork the repo to start diving in right into your thesis project!

Comment: Please can you explain here how to use it?  What are the known problems, is someone there fixing bugs etc.  A link only answer is not the best way here, suppose the given link is broken, then the given answer is useless.