# Aligning text and images in titlepage using minipage

Tags: titles, minipage

I am trying to make a titlepage for my Thesis. I am using this titlepage as a draft [UNAM thesis title page (portada tesis UNAM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234265/unam-thesis-title-page-portada-tesis-unam) but I want to add a third Logo in the upper right corner and I am having trouble with minipage because this logo appear in the middle instead of the top of the page.

Do you know a solution for this?

Here is my MWE

```
\begin{titlepage}
    % if you want the titlepage to be centered, uncomment and fine-tune the line below (KOMA classes environment)
    \begin{addmargin}[0cm]{-3cm}
\begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
  \flushleft
  \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gfx/Logo1}}

  \vspace{20pt}

  \center{
    \rule{.5pt}{.6\textheight}
    \hspace{7pt}
    \rule{2pt}{.6\textheight}
    \hspace{7pt}
    \rule{.5pt}{.6\textheight}
  } \\

  \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gfx/Logo2}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}

\center{
 \spacedallcaps{TECNOLÓGICO NACIONAL DE MÉXICO} \\
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
  \\
  \hrulefill\\[1cm]  
\spacedallcaps{INSTITUTO TECNOLÓGICO DE CELAYA}\\[2cm]
        \begingroup
            \color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps{Título} \\[2cm]         \endgroup
  \huge{T \hspace{1cm} E \hspace{1cm} S \hspace{1cm} I \hspace{1cm} S  }\\[1cm]
  \large{QUE PARA OBTENER EL TÍTULO DE:}\\[1cm]
  \large{Ingeniero Mecánico}\\[1cm]
  \large{PRESENTA:}\\[1cm]
  \large{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Yo}}\\[1cm]
  \large{TUTOR:}\\[1cm]
    \large{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Tutor}}\\[1cm]
  \large{Departamento}
}
        \vfill

        Fecha
        \vfill                      
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
    \flushright
    \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gfx/Logo3}}
\vfill  
\end{minipage}

  \end{addmargin}       
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the textpos package?

Comment: This titlepage smells of classicthesis and is full of errors. I recommend to scrap it and start from scratch.

Comment: You can also use tikzpagenodes to overlay logos etc. at specific locations on the page.

Comment: @Johannes_B It took me a while but so far it has been working right, if I start to have more trouble I´ll switch the formatting. I don't think this minipage issue is related with the classicthesis class

Answer (score 0):

Align the minipages at the `[t]`op.

> Attention, the following code is unmodified as presented by the OP and *is wrong*.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    % if you want the titlepage to be centered, uncomment and fine-tune the line below (KOMA classes environment)
    \begin{addmargin}[0cm]{-3cm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
  \flushleft
  \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

  \vspace{20pt}

  \center{
    \rule{.5pt}{.6\textheight}
    \hspace{7pt}
    \rule{2pt}{.6\textheight}
    \hspace{7pt}
    \rule{.5pt}{.6\textheight}
  } \\

  \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}

\center{
 \spacedallcaps{TECNOLÓGICO NACIONAL DE MÉXICO} \\
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
  \\
  \hrulefill\\[1cm]  
\spacedallcaps{INSTITUTO TECNOLÓGICO DE CELAYA}\\[2cm]
        \begingroup
            \color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps{Título} \\[2cm]         \endgroup
  \huge{T \hspace{1cm} E \hspace{1cm} S \hspace{1cm} I \hspace{1cm} S  }\\[1cm]
  \large{QUE PARA OBTENER EL TÍTULO DE:}\\[1cm]
  \large{Ingeniero Mecánico}\\[1cm]
  \large{PRESENTA:}\\[1cm]
  \large{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Yo}}\\[1cm]
  \large{TUTOR:}\\[1cm]
    \large{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Tutor}}\\[1cm]
  \large{Departamento}
}
        \vfill

        Fecha
        \vfill                      
\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
    \flushright
    \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\vfill  
\end{minipage}

  \end{addmargin}       
\end{titlepage}   
\end{document}
```