# How to resize/scale a whole title page if it is not a pdf or a graphic?

Tags: titles, resize

So I am creating a title page for my thesis, I am using Classicthesis, and I am using this title page as a draft [UNAM thesis title page (portada tesis UNAM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234265/unam-thesis-title-page-portada-tesis-unam). The issue I am having is that the titlepage appears very tiny and is not centered I would like that my titlepage fits the whole page.

Here is my titlepage code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    %*******************************************************
    % Titlepage
    %*******************************************************
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.2\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
%                   \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{gfx/Logo_ITC_cl.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }
        \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    {\scshape{TECNOLOGICO NACIONAL DE MEXICO}}
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    \hrule height2.5pt
                    \vspace{.1cm}
                    \hrule height1pt
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    {\scshape {INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO DE CELAYA}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }

        \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.2\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \hskip2pt
                    \vrule width2.5pt height10cm
                    \hskip1mm
                    \vrule width1pt height10cm \\
                    %\includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth]{gfx/Logo-TecNM.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }
        \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
                \vspace*{1cm}
                \begin{center}
                    {\Large \scshape {\begingroup \color{red}{myTitle}
                            \endgroup}}

                    \vspace{2cm}

                    \makebox[5cm][c]{\huge T \hspace{0.5cm} E \hspace{0.5cm} S \hspace{0.5cm} I \hspace{0.5cm} S  }  \\[8pt]
                    QUE PARA OBTENER EL TITULO DE:\\[5pt]
                    {\large{myDegree}}\\[40pt]            
                    PRESENTA:\\[5pt]
                    {\large{myName}}

                    \vspace{1cm}

                    {TUTOR:\\ \large{{myProf}}}

                    \vspace{0.5cm}

                    myTime
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{titlepage}   
\end{document}
```

And this is the output

[image: Output1]

I tried using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{content}` but this happens:
[image: Output2]

Any ideas?

John Kormylo solved it in a very acurate way.

Another solution I found is putting every minipage beetwen scalebox{1.2}{content} from the graphicx package, it does the trick but is not as sharp and acurate as John Kormylo's.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Excuse me if I was not clear enough, I want the titlepage to fit the whole page, you can see in the pictures that I am not achieving this. Also I think that it is neccesary to include all the elements of my titlepage that is why the long MWE

Comment: It was designed that way: .2\textwidth+.65\textwidth=.85\textwidth.  Perhaps it is intentional.

Comment: The `adjustbox` package gives you a `adjustbox` environment which allows you to scale its content, e.g. `\begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\textwidth,width=\textwidth} ... \end{adjustbox}`. You could also add `height=\textheight,keepaspectratio` if the height is limiting the zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code was wasting space.  This version uses all of it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{showframe}% show extent of text area

\newlength{\maxwidth}
\newlength{\maxheight}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\maxwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule-\lineskip}%
\setlength{\maxheight}{\dimexpr \textheight-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule-\lineskip}%
    %*******************************************************
    % Titlepage
    %*******************************************************
        \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\maxheight][c]{0.25\maxwidth}
                \begin{center}
%                   \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{gfx/Logo_ITC_cl.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}%
        }\hskip\lineskip% symmetry
        \fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\maxheight][c]{0.75\maxwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    {\scshape{TECNOLOGICO NACIONAL DE MEXICO}}
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    \hrule height2.5pt
                    \vspace{.1cm}
                    \hrule height1pt
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    {\scshape {INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO DE CELAYA}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}%
        }\allowbreak
        \fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.9\maxheight][t]{0.25\maxwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \hskip2pt
                    \vrule width2.5pt height0.9\maxheight
                    \hskip1mm
                    \vrule width1pt height0.9\maxheight \\
                    %\includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth]{gfx/Logo-TecNM.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}%
        }\hskip\lineskip
        \fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.9\maxheight][c]{0.75\maxwidth}
                \vspace*{1cm}
                \begin{center}
                    {\Large \scshape {\begingroup \color{red}{myTitle}
                            \endgroup}}

                    \vspace{2cm}

                    \makebox[5cm][c]{\huge T \hspace{0.5cm} E \hspace{0.5cm} S \hspace{0.5cm} I \hspace{0.5cm} S  }  \\[8pt]
                    QUE PARA OBTENER EL TITULO DE:\\[5pt]
                    {\large{myDegree}}\\[40pt]            
                    PRESENTA:\\[5pt]
                    {\large{myName}}

                    \vspace{1cm}

                    {TUTOR:\\ \large{{myProf}}}

                    \vspace{0.5cm}

                    myTime
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}%
        }
    \end{titlepage}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: You solved it in an excellent manner